# What is the purpose of "gar" in a (non-negative) interrogative?

Tags: meaning

> Stehen **gar** die Dinge so schlecht, dass ... ?

A person in a novel used *gar* like this, though there's not a negative element in the sentence. The *so* already emphasizes *schlecht*, so what is the purpose of *gar* (placed far away from *so*) in an interrogative?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/gar#2, II

Comment: *gar* → *sogar*. The *so* is sometimes skipped if there is another *so* in the phrase.

Comment: @Janka So this "(so)gar / even" is used emphatically, compared to whatever is discussed in a previous sentence?

Comment: Usually, yes. But it may also be a comparision to *in Ordnung*.

Answer (score 1):

**Gar** entspricht mehr oder weniger dem englischen **even**. **Gar** kann ebenso als Kurzform für **sogar** verwendet werden und ist eher poetisch. In der Umgangssprache wird das Wort vergleichsweise selten benutzt - und wenn dann meistens in Verbindung mit **nicht**:

> Ich war das aber **gar nicht**!

**Gar** equals more or less the english **even**. It can be used as a short form of **sogar**. It is not used often except in novels and books. If it is used in workaday life it appears mostly with a **nicht** afterwards.

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT:**

In manchen Fällen (wie in deinem Beispiel) könnte man das Wort **gar** auch mit **doch** tauschen:

> Stehen die Dinge **doch** so schlecht, dass...?

greetings

Comment: no it was not. my edit is just the "edit" block in german at the bottom...you simply did not read my answer

Comment: Deine Formulierung scheint mir ungenau, "gar nicht" ist ganz und gar nicht selten.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass "gar" für "sogar" benutzt werden kann.

Comment: @messerbill OK, sorry, then I really didn't see the German part of your answer. Apologies!

Comment: @CarstenS natürlich geht das! Dass "gar nicht" selten ist, habe ich nie gesagt....und was das andere angeht: **Ist er ein schlechter Spieler? - Nein! Er ist (so)gar der beste!**. Das kann man auf jeden Fall sagen...

Comment: Wenn du nicht meinst, dass "gar nicht" selten ist, dann kannst Du "selten, und wenn dann" zum Beispiel durch "selten, außer" ersetzen.